# second modal button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My second, third and so on buttons which open modal, doesn't work and I can't figure out the problem.

I think is a logic problem in my javascript code for sure, but I can't find a way to solve it ... maybe you can help me.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');
var buton = document.getElementById('continut');

buton.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = img.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

//When the user clicks on <span> (X), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

You have a demonstration on jsfiddle

Thanks in advance !

https://jsfiddle.net/qschptk9/1/

I've got 2 negative votes, and NO ONE Helped me.

Ok i've Changed the ID's, but still doesn't work, because getElementsByClassName return an array of elements ...

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. Of course you’re going to get into trouble if you reuse IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id should be unique so you should't use it for 2 elements
you use the same id 2 times for many elemets (button, modal, img, modalimg)
you can change the id's for all those elements (hard coded option), or you can add a class for both and add click event for both but you will need to differentiate each modal and each img (you can do this by passing ids for these elements in a function)

**Edit**

this is an optimized solution that i would use for you want to do

I added only one modal and used onclick event for each button to pass the header text and the img id to a function that show the appropriate modal
here is the HTML

```
<div class="portfolio_content">
    <div class="row" id="portfolio">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 websites responsive webDesign">
            <div class="portfolio_single_content">
                <img id="myImg1" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="title" />
                <div>
                    <!--Continut because from here we access the content of this preview photo-->
                    <div class="continut">
                        <p>Portfolio Website</p>
                        <button class="seeBtn" onclick="showModal('Portfolio Website','myImg1')">
                            button
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 appsDevelopment">
            <div class="portfolio_single_content">
                <img id="myImg2" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="title" />
                <div>
                    <!--Continut because from here we access the content of this preview photo-->
                    <div class="continut">
                        <p>Pomodoro Clock</p>
                        <button class="seeBtn" onclick="showModal('Pomodoro Clock','myImg2')">
                            button
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--The modal-->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!--Modal header-->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close" id="close">CLOSE X<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <h2 id="modal_h1"></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img class="modal-image" id="img01">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>External <a href="" target="_blank">link</a></h3>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the js code

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');
var modalHeaderTxt = document.getElementById('modal_h1');

function showModal(header_txt,img_id){
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal
    var img = document.getElementById(img_id);
    modalImg.src = img.src;
    modalHeaderTxt.innerHTML = header_txt;
    modal.style.display = "block";

}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("close");

//When the user clicks on <span> (X), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zwf662yn/)

and here is the hard coded option (i don't recommend it)

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var img2 = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');
var modalImg2 = document.getElementById('img02');
var buton = document.getElementById('continut');
var buton2 = document.getElementById('continut2');

buton.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = img.src;
}
buton2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
  modalImg2.src = img2.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

//When the user clicks on <span> (X), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zdecfv16/)

Comment: Don't we have a short "hard-coded" way ? Because this is what I'm trying to figure out ..

Comment: yes i'm workin on optimized way which will make it flexible for any number of modals, i will post it once i finish.

Comment: @AdrianGheorghe I update my answer please check the firs demo, i hope it helps :).

Comment: Definetly you have more experience than me, and thank you very much for sharing it !

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the id's for the models to classes. You can't assign multiple id's in HTML. That's why your code works only for one modal.

Change your id's to classes like this:

```
 <div class="modal myModal">
```

Comment: This should be a comment. It points out a problem, but doesn't offer a clear solution.

Comment: Hmm i thought it was a pretty clear solution to just change the id's, but you are right, i changed it to make it clearer.

Comment: How do you expect to change the style property on a list of elements?

Comment: getElementsByClassName returs an array of elements so you can't acces it with modal.style.display, also he has 2 buttons with the same id.

Comment: Do I have a way to solve this problem ?
Because I as you say, I can't access them with modal.style.display

Answer (score 1):

You have two id's with same name hence first id will be picked everytime. The ids must be unique. Please try changing the id and it should work.
Or you can try to change it into class names and then work with classes

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. *"changing the id"* and *"change it into class names"* provides hardly any information to the OP other than being helpful statements. Those are comments, not answers.

Comment: Not sure how its not an answer. Solution offered was to either change the id  or to use class names. Code Sample was not given but enough pointers were there that helps to proceed in the right direction.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question in the same way *"Just fix the code"* doesn't answer the question. Just changing the id's or classes will not work, the OP's code needs to be redone to work with many id's and/or classes as well.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have more than one `element` that has `id='myModal'`
, in that case you should do:

`var modal = document.getElementById('myModal')[correct element number]`

example :
document.getElementById('myModal')[0] *//for the first element*
document.getElementById('myModal')[1] *//for the second element*
and so on...
for each button